# php copy issue with foreach loop-only last image being uploaded

Tags: php

i am trying to upload remote file using below code for testing purpose and to my surprise only last images are being uploaded.. i changed the sequence of images and it was always last image which was uploading rest are failing. inbrowser console i can see below error.

**Warning**:  copy(http://example.com/your-heart.jpg
): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in **/home/example/minimum.php** on line **205**
 it is coming from form with text field name is urls

here is my php

```
 $image_links = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);

   $i = 1;
   foreach($image_links as $image_link){
      $file_info = pathinfo($image_link);
      copy($image_link, '/home/xxxxx/00' . $i . '_original.' . $file_info['extension']);
      $i++;

   }
```

any help will be great. 
i tried so many different things for copy parameters like single quote, double quote and several other things but always same output. only last image upload and it says all other images are not found. i even tried to replace http with www . my sample urls are 
http://example.com/color-your-heart.jpg
output of var dump

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(61) "http://example.com/thumb/color-your-heart.jpg
"
  [1]=>
  string(64) "http://example.com/thumb/mobile-price-real-time-calculator.png"
}
```

Comment: Remove the link from the URL, it is spam!

Comment: @MikeVelazco its xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com not my site samplelink i gave. removing

Comment: @MikeVelazco thanks for pointing out. i think unknowingly i had marked some wrong site

Comment: Are you downloading the images from user provided URL's?, it's just a suggestion, but this could be a HUGE security issue.

Comment: Is the image links you tried to explode is really exploded correctly? Can you please `var_dump()` and put your result?

Comment: @MikeVelazco yes and we are taking care of security. users are  submitting image links after checking we are saving in server

Comment: @TareqAziz giving in 2 minutes

Comment: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(61) "http://example.com/thumb/facebook-fun/color-your-heart.jpg
"
  [1]=>
  string(64) "http://example.com/thumb/mobile-price-real-time-calculator.png"
}

Comment: is `$image_link` being url encoded? did you have `&` or other characters in your tests? Have you tried using `curl`? posted too late: that &quot; is going to cause you issues

Comment: @DaveGoten there is no & quote. i pasted in notepad and then pasted here and seems stackoverflow is automatically encodeing. pasting the output of dump in question

Comment: @swetlana Ah, ya that would make sense, seems Barmar noticed the other issue, if it' a space, `\r` or other white-space character trim should have you covered.

Comment: @DaveGoten i tried \r but that did not worked but barmar trim is working. i will cover all issues pointed out by experts here.thanks sir for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a space after the filename in the error message. Try removing spaces with `trim()`

```
copy(trim($image_link), '/home/xxxxx/00' . $i . '_original.' . $file_info['extension']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use like below.

```
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$fileext = 'jpg'; // ext
$thenew_name = 'new random name or something';
$file = $upload_dir . '/' . $thenew_name . '.' . $fileext;
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
```

Then use `$file` with additional relative directory path to save the image for you, like replace `$upload_dir` with your path variable. You can use into your foreach loop also. Also remove all the extra pert from image url. Most of expert said you in comments.